# In java , is it possible that static polymorphic method can apply to super class

Tags: java

I don't know how to describe the question exactly, sorry!
I have a class（E） base on a base class（B） , and in a helper class（Printer） ,two same name methods (printIt).
These printIt methods use B or E as parameter, this is static polymorphism.

```
public class B {
    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("i am b");
    }
}


public class E extends B {
    @Override
    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println("i am e");
    }
}

public class Printer {

    public void printIt(B b) {
        System.out.println("it is b");
    }

//    public void printIt(B b) {
//        if (b.getClass().equals(B.class)) {
//            System.out.println("it is b");
//        } else if (b.getClass().equals(E.class)) {
//            E e = (E) b;
//            printIt(e);
//        }
//    }

    public void printIt(E e) {
        System.out.println("it is e");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        E e = new E();

        B be = e;

        System.out.println("------------dynamic polymorphism ---------------");
        b.printMe();    //i am b
        e.printMe();    //i am e

        be.printMe();   //i am e


        System.out.println("------------static polymorphism ----------------");
        Printer printer = new Printer();

        printer.printIt(b);     //it is b
        printer.printIt(e);     //it is e


        System.out.println("-------------????????????????? -----------------");
        printer.printIt(be);    //it is b
    }
}
```

In above code, the last printIt call will use "public void printIt(E e)" method to print " it is b ".  But "be" variable is a "E" object in fact , is there a way in "Printer" let java to choice method according to the class of object passed in.

If i switch comments on "printIt(B b)" in above code, i wil get what i want, but is it tedious, because if I add many subclass of "B", i have to add many else if in it.

Comment: `be` is declared as `B` and hence it will call `printIt(B)`. At this point the type of the variable does matter, not the actuall class that `be` does refer to.

Comment: Additionally that is called overloading what your `printIt` method is doing.

Comment: tl;dr: in case of overloaded method, the **static** (aka compile-time) types of the parameters are used to resolve the method-call. In your case, `be` is of static type `B` and therefore `printer.println(B b)` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid these kinds of overloads. Where one parameter is a parent of the other.

It is up to the caller to pick which method gets called, which could easily break encapsulation:

```
printer.printIt(be);    //it is b
printer.printIt((E) be);    //it is e
```

---

Checking the dynamic type of `be` incurs extra runtime cost, so it is not done by default.

You could implement it yourself however:

```
class Printer {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<Printer, ?>> map = new HashMap<>();
    private static final BiConsumer<Printer, B> defaultConsumer = (p, b) -> System.out.println("it is b");

    static {
        for(Method m : Printer.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if(m.getName().equals("printIt")) {
                Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();

                if(params.length == 1 && !params[0].equals(B.class)) {
                    map.put(params[0], (p, b) -> {
                        try {
                            m.invoke(p, b);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Should never happens
                            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid method mapping");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> void printIt(B b) {
        ((BiConsumer<Printer, T>) map.getOrDefault(b.getClass(), defaultConsumer)).accept(this, (T) b);
    }

    public void printIt(E e) {
        System.out.println("it is e");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It Seems to me that you simply don't understand the basic ideas behind polymorphism properly. You were completely on the right track but got lost when writing the the printer class which should look like this:

```
public class Printer {

    public void printIt(B b) {
        b.printMe();
    }
}
```

This is a very everyday use of polymorphism that seems to perfectly fill your need?

Comment: +1 The classes in the inheritance hierarchy should provide their implementation of the print method, which are then called by the Printer class. Much cleaner code, easier to understand, better encapsulation.

Comment: I agree. Maybe  printMe method mislead the question. In my  real case , there is no  that method. The B and E class is from another Frameworks .